# Filter mysql results based on multiselect box

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, multi-select

I am trying to filter a mysql table based upon the values in a multiselect box so that it returns all results who's values have been selected. For instance this is my multiple select box:

```
<select name="gift[]" id="gift" multiple="multiple" onchange="change()">
            <option value="him">Him</option>
            <option value="her">Her</option>
            <option value="kids">Kids</option>
            <option value="teens">Teens</option>
            <option value="mothersday">Mothers Day</option>
            <option value="fathersday">Fathers Day</option>
            <option value="valentines">Valentines Day</option>
            <option value="gadgets">Gadgets</option>
            <option value="secretsanta">Secret Santa</option>
</select>
```

If a user selects "him" and "gadgets" it should return all results from the mysql table with either "him" or "gadgets" in it.

The mysql table has the data for each product stored in a single column as a string (i.e. under column 'gift' it might say him,her,kids,gadgets or for another row it might be her,gadgets. With the example above I want it to return both rows).

The results are returned by AJAX and I have tried to use the WHERE IN clause but unable to get it working.Here is my code (HTML select box already above):

AJAX *note: not full code for simplicity*

```
function change(){
var giftarray = new Array();
$.each($("#gift option:selected"), function(){            
        giftarray.push($(this).val());
 });

 var gift = "'" + giftarray.join("','") + "'";

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("product").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}

var url="results.php"
url=url+"&gift="+gift;

xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Results.PHP *note: not full code for simplicity*

```
$gift=$_GET['gift'];
$gift=str_replace("\\","",$gift);
$sql= "SELECT * FROM $productstable WHERE gift IN ($gift)";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Unable to run query:'.mysql_error());
while($item = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
code to view products here
}
<? } mysql_close()  ?>
```

Mysql Table and data *Note: I've only shown the gift column, id and data for two rows (hope this is ok)*

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
`id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`gift` varchar(100) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `products` VALUES(1,'him,her');
INSERT INTO `products` VALUES(2,'him,her,teens,gadgets');
```

This seems to work if the product has only one value assigned to it in the mysql table but doesn't when it has multiple. From what i've read I think I may be going wrong with storing multiple criteria in a single column but not sure how to fix it. Many Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some sample from your database table that you are working with?

Comment: still using raw javascript for AJAX ? Consider using jQuery! Also, stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions; use MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Database script added, also thanks Raptor, ill change it over. Any ideas why it isnt working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing this wrong way.

First, read about database normalization. You must have 3 tables.

```
type { id, title } for storing him,her,teens,gadgets as rows with unique id
product { id, product_title, ...... } for storing products
product_type {product_id, type_id} to store relation product -> type
```

You must send options data as array:

```
index.php?options[1]=him&options[2]=her&options[3]=kids
```

And then in PHP you get it as:

```
$options = $_GET['options'];
```

Then you can build query using join:

```
$q = "SELECT a.id, a.product_title from product a JOIN product_type b ON a.a=b.product_id WHERE b.type_id IN('".implode("','",$options )."')";
```

p.s.
This is just example. Very insecure. You must need prepared statements for security, validate input data, create right indexes. You can store "type" in array with IDs, but I prefer storing in database.

Your example wrong from the side of relation database design. Furthermore, using LIKE is very inefficient.

Comment: Thank you, I knew there must be a more logical way. Ill give this a try. Just to confirm, in the type table where the gift options are stored, would the gifts still be stored in a comma delimited list or should each have its own column? Also is the third table actually necessary or is this possible with just the first two?

Comment: gift options are stored as rows! Table type will have only 2 columns: id, title

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i've found a solution but pretty sure its not the correct way as its not very elegant. Any suggestions for improvements welcome. I set explode $gift variable into an array and then produce several OR LIKE statements with wildcards to match. Lookily there are only 9 options in my multiselect box as this method would soon become tedious.

CODE:
RESULTS.PHP

```
$gift=$_GET['gift'];
$gift=str_replace("\\","",$gift);
$gift=str_replace("'","%",$gift);
$gift=explode(",",$gift);

$sql= "SELECT * 
FROM $productstable 
WHERE gift LIKE '$gift[0]' 
OR gift LIKE '$gift[1]' 
OR gift LIKE '$gift[2]' 
OR gift LIKE '$gift[3]' 
OR gift LIKE '$gift[4]' 
OR gift LIKE '$gift[5]' 
OR gift LIKE '$gift[6]' 
OR gift LIKE '$gift[7]' 
OR gift LIKE '$gift[8]'
OR gift LIKE '$gift[9]'";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Unable to run query:'.mysql_error());
while($item = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
code to view products here
}
<? } mysql_close()  ?>
```

Not liking this method at all really as thought IN was supposed to do the same but just couldnt get it to work. Would this have negative implications with speed?

Also going to recode this using PDO later.